# How to fix 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error when using option group in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form in MS Access with two options and one command button. When option `1` is selected and the command button clicked, a Select query must run, and when option `2` is selected and the command button clicked, a Delete query must run.

Below is my code; I am getting the error:

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CmdViewDeleteRecords_Click()
    Select Case Me.OptionViewDelete
        Case Is = 1
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qrySelectRecords", acViewNormal, acEdit
        Case Is = 2
            DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryDeleteRecords"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: Lee Mac, The highlighted line is : Select Case Me.OptionViewDelete

Comment: Have you used the name `OptionViewDelete` elsewhere in your project for a different object/function/module?

Comment: No, I created OptionViewDelete only for this sub

Comment: So what is `Me.OptionViewDelete`?  Is it an option frame/group control?

Comment: Should be **Case 1**, not **Case Is = 1**

Comment: @Rene  See [online docs for Select Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement).  The `Is` keyword is optional, but it is valid syntax.  There is no difference between the two expressions.

Comment: @ C Perkins, I stand corrected.

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake in my question. The frame name is ViewDelete. The labelname is 'OptionViewDelete'. My bad! :(  Thanks a lot to LeeMac, Perkins and Rene for trying to help. Really appreciate it!. Its all working good now.